# python/mysqldb cur.execute not inserting values

Tags: mysql-python

This code is not inserting any value into the table. I do not understand why. Please help. PS - it runs properly and prints true but does not insert anything.

```
import face_recognition
import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",  # your host, usually localhost
    user="root",  # your username
    passwd=" ",  # your password
    db="staticdb",  # name of the data base
)

cur = db.cursor()

picture_of_me = face_recognition.load_image_file(
    "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/akriti/student_images/201501431/reference/201501431.png"
)
my_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(picture_of_me)[0]

# my_face_encoding now contains a universal 'encoding' of my
# facial features that can be compared to any other picture of a face!

unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file(
    "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/akriti/student_images/201501431/2018-05-03_100/201501431.jpg"
)
unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]

# Now we can see the two face encodings are of the same person with `compare_faces`!

results = face_recognition.compare_faces(
    [my_face_encoding], unknown_face_encoding
)


if results[0] == True:
    cur.execute(
        """insert into attendance  (StudentId,TheDate,CourseId) values (%s,%s,%s) """,
        ("201501890", "2018-05-03", "100"),
    )
    print("true")
    db.commit()
```

Comment: You haven't created table attendance. Or is it already available into database?

Comment: Already available

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma at the end of your query. Don't know what for. But Try this. This should work.

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO attendance (StudentId,TheDate,CourseId) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", ('201501890','2018-05-03','100'))
```